# Правильно ли мокать функцию внешнего модуля?

Tags: python, юнит-тесты, pytest, mock

Мне нужно протестировать, что корректно обрабатываются результаты внешней программы, но сам вызов программы не делать. Этот вызов делаю функцией run внешнего модуля subprocess. Правильно ли мокать непосредственно функцию run? Нет ли рисков, например, что тест сломается например от изменения конструктора класса CompletedProcess? Или по каким то другим причинам. Может быть сделать обертку для run и ее мокать?

```
import pytest
import subprocess 

def func1():
    # ... здесь еще код
    completed_process = subprocess.run()
    # ... здесь еще код

    return completed_process.returncode == 0

def testfunc1(monkeypatch):
    def mock1(*args):
        return subprocess.CompletedProcess(args = '', returncode = 0)

    monkeypatch.setattr('subprocess.run', mock1)

    assert func1()
```

Comment: Лучше сделать обертку и дополнительно нужен еще интеграционный тест

Comment: @RomanKonoval почему считаете что нужна обертка? интеграционный тест для чего?

Comment: Я бы сказал, что и так сойдет. Вряд ли в ближайшие десятилетия модуль subprocess прямо так кардинально изменится, а даже если и изменится, то у вас тесты упадут, тогда и поправите. Можно конечно в mock1 возвращать не CompletedProcess, а мок-объект с аналогичными атрибутами, но вряд ли это сильно улучшит код.

Comment: @insolor В общем согласен, что я перестраховался говоря что сломается тест, но обертку решил сделать всё таки, чтобы, как минимум, не использовать конструктор у CompletedProcess, т.к. в реальной работе программист этот конструктор не используется вроде как.